# Django rest framework - "This field is required."

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have two classes, class Amount and Transaction

```
class Account(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
account_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
currency = models.CharField(max_length=3)
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, default=0)


class Transaction(models.Model):
sender_account_number = models.BigIntegerField()
recipient_account_number = models.BigIntegerField()
amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My serializers:

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ['sender_account_number', 'recipient_account_number', 'amount', 'date_creation', 'account']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'date_creation': {'read_only': True},

        }``

class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ['id', 'account_number', 'currency', 'balance', 'user']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'balance': {'read_only': True},
            'user': {'read_only': True},
        }
```

I want to add a transaction to the database, but so that it automatically sets my account_id based on the account number, because one user can have multiple accounts*.
I tried the perform_create method

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(account=Account.objects.values('id').filter(
        account_number=self.request.data['sender_account_number']))
```

but I failed. I get error

```
{
"account": [
    "This field is required."
]
```

}

for example, I want to send these data

```
{

"sender_account_number": 346,
"recipient_account_number": 546,
"amount": 60

}
```

and Post method:

```
def post(self, request):   
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Since you don't want to send `account` in your request data and you are looking to handle it manually, just remove it from `fields` list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to tell your transaction serializer that account is a foreign key. And hence, it would expect an object instead of a string.
add account = serializers.StringRelatedField() like so

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        account = serializers.StringRelatedField()
        class Meta:
            model = Transaction
            fields = ['sender_account_number', 'recipient_account_number', 'amount', 'date_creation', 'account']
            extra_kwargs = {
                'date_creation': {'read_only': True},
    
            }``
```

You do not need the perform create function if you do that. serializer should automatically add it for you. you just have to retrieve from your account models, the instance with your account number. then pass it into the serializer.save() after checking if serializer is valid. like so

```
def post(self, request):
    account_number = request.data.get('sender_account_number')
    account = Account.objects.get(account_number=account)
    serializer = TransactionSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        serializer.save(account = account_number)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```